# Access to common library

Tags: git, typescript, bitbucket-pipelines

I've got a typescript project that is a library of common methods that we want to make available to other repos in our organization. We don't want the transpiled code in the repo so we are including the dist folder in gitignore. Of course we need the transpiled code in order to distribute and came across the idea to use a push back in bitbucket as described here: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/push-back-to-your-repository/

In theory what we are attempting is to follow the 'normal' branching strategy with pull requests in lower branches but once merged to the master branch, copy the dist folder, commit to bitbucket and tag. This tagged version would then be used by other repos.

Here are the bitbucket-pipelines.yml entries:

```
    master:
  - step: *Lint
  - step: *Test
  - step: *Build
  - step: *PushDistToRepo
```

The PushDistToRepo step only happens in master. Here is what that step does:

```
    - step: &Lint
    name: Lint
    caches:
      - node
    script:
      - npm ci
      - npm run lint
- step: &Test
    name: Unit Tests
    caches:
      - node
    script:
      - npm ci
      - npm run test
- step: &Build
    name: Build the repository
    caches:
      - node
    script:
      - npm ci
      - npm run build
- step: &PushDistToRepo
    name: Push the build artifact '\dist' back to repo
    trigger: manual # Uncomment to make this a manual deployment.
    caches:
      - node
    script:
      - git add -f dist/
      - git commit -m "[skip ci] Updating the build artifiact in build ${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}"
      - git push
```

When we run this in the pipeline this error occurs on step -git add -f dist/:

```
fatal: pathspec 'dist/' did not match any files
```

So it seems that the dist folder doesn't exist or can't be created. Any ideas?

Comment: you likely want to publish your builds into an artifactory of some type, either global (like npm) or something local to your organization.

Answer (score 0):

Each step in your pipeline runs in a separate container<sup>[1](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-bitbucket-pipelinesyml/)</sup>, so any files created in a previous step are not available in the next step by default.

You have two options, either run the build and commit scripts in the same step, or use artifacts<sup>[2](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-artifacts-in-steps/)</sup>.

When using artifacts the configuration for the Build build would look something like the following.

```yaml
- step: &Build
    name: Build the repository
    caches:
      - node
    script:
      - npm ci
      - npm run build
    artifacts: # defining the artifacts to be passed to each future step.
      - dist/**
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. If I understand correctly when I add artifacts to the build step that will  result in the dist folder being copied for all the other branches since the build step is common. I suppose thats ok since they expire in 14 days but it seems like why not remove the dist folder from gitignore and carry the files along. Maybe I'm missing something here though. Also, will the PushDistToRepo step I added that does the commit to master be able to access the artifact from a previous step? Thanks again

Comment: Looks like the artifact approach will work for our needs. Thank you very much